# Powerpoint VBA References

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I am writing a VBA code on Powerpoint, where I need to call and excel file for input. Programme is functioning fine, runs without error, and generates output, except for the part where Excel file is called. It simply does not open the Excel file.

Wrote 3-4 lines to just call an excel file and it also runs without error, but does not open the file.
I suspect I am missing something in References.

The code is:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Booki As Excel.Application
Set Booki = New Excel.Application

Booki.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Kashyap\Desktop\Test.xlsx"

End Sub
```

The References added are:
a) Visual Basic for applications
b) Microsoft powerpoint 14.0 Object library
c) OLE Automation
d) Microsoft Office 14.0 Object library
e) Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object library

Can anyone let me know what library I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the newly opened instance of Excel, you have to make it visible (see below).
You'll also want to close the workbook and excel when done, else you'll have orphaned tasks hanging around eating memory.  In fact, before testing the code below, start Task Manager, look at Processes and kill any Excel.exe instances.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Booki As Excel.Application
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook

Set Booki = New Excel.Application

Set Wb = Booki.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xlsx")

' if you want to SEE the result,
Booki.Visible = True

' show us something from the workbook to prove that it's open:
MsgBox Wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value

Wb.Close
Booki.Quit

Set Wb = Nothing
Set Booki = Nothing

End Sub
```